# Django shuts down intermittenly

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a django application running on apache2 and mod_wsgi. Recently the server started getting restarted / shut down intermittently without a uniform frequency. Is there a chance that it happens when some specific .py files are accessed? My error log seems to be empty however.

Comment: Could be absolutely anything, some flavours of linux will kill a random app if the memory usage gets too high. But you won't find anything in your django error log since it isn't a django issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the individual Django processes, or the Apache server as a whole?

If you are using embedded mode of mod_wsgi (you shouldn't and should use daemon mode), then it is normal for Apache to stop and start worker processes running your Django application based on how much traffic the site is receiving.

On Linux systems, log file rotation systems might also be triggering Apache as a whole to restart. You also can memory usage monitoring whereby services can be killed off if they use too much memory.

To provide further guidance about whether Apache is restarting processes, you would need to indicate what your configuration is.

Also make sure you read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. There were two issues, our maxrequest value was set to low and the max_pool_size of mongoclient(inside the code) also had a cap. Setting the max_pool_size to unlimited and raising the maxrequest value in mpm_prefork configuration seems to have fixed the issue.